# Group data based on column label in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I've been reading about hierarchical index and multiindex in a pandas dataframe but it seems these are all for ordered labels. For example, my data looks like this:

[image]

And I want to be able to group the data together based on the column label ie. aggregate all columns with 'd' in row 3 together by averaging.

What is the best way to get this excel data (or csv if absolutely needed) into a dataframe so that I can do these operations and how would I go about doing them?

Any advice or references would be appreciated

**EDIT**

I tried loading the data from a csv using the following command:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv', index_col=0, header=[0,1,2,3], parse_dates=True)
```

which gives me this when loaded:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 18 entries, 2013-05-27 10:31:00 to 2013-07-24 11:31:00
Data columns (total 40 columns):
(1, mix, d, n)     18  non-null values
(2, aq, s, n)      18  non-null values
(3, gr, s, n)      18  non-null values
(4, mix, d, n)     18  non-null values
(5, aq, d, n)      17  non-null values
```

I'm just not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: where are you reading the data from ? Excel file or CSV? if so take a look in the CSV module in Python.

Comment: I would preferably want to read from excel but I did look into converting to a csv then set the headers as the rows I want to be able to group with but I don't know where to go from there. I'll add an edit and show you what I mean.

Comment: have you tried with `data['3']` like the 10 min. tutorial shows?

Comment: I just watched the video and no that doesn't seem to work it just gives me a key error.

Comment: Can you post what you tried and the error you got? (and maybe also the data itself as raw text instead of an image)

Comment: I think your keys are `'(3, gr, s, n)'` but I am not a pandas user. Can't really know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use column-wise (`axis=1`) [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and take the [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=[[1, 2, 3], ['d', 's', 'd']])

In [12]: df.columns.names = ['PLOT', 'DEPTH']

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
PLOT          1         2         3
DEPTH         d         s         d
0     -0.557490 -1.231495 -0.333703
1      0.513394  1.046577  0.596306
2     -0.404606 -1.615080 -0.694562
3     -0.078497 -0.683405  0.056857

In [14]: df.groupby(level='DEPTH', axis=1).mean()
Out[14]:
DEPTH         d         s
0     -0.445596 -1.231495
1      0.554850  1.046577
2     -0.549584 -1.615080
3     -0.010820 -0.683405
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do! I did some variation of this previously but was not going about it the right way. Thanks!